# Getting ViewCell content in ListView.ItemSelected

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm having an issue with ListView in XAML.
I try to achieve a ExpandableList with opening animation. For this I wanted to use a ListView and StackLayout.

In the ItemSelected event, I would like to add values to the stacklayout and then increase the Height animated. But how do I get a reference to the ViewCell?

And further, is there a way to get the calculated height of the stacklayout and use LayoutTo to this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to put an `IsSelected` property on whatever class makes up the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` and set its value to `true` in your `ItemSelected` handler. Then you can subclass `ViewCell` and respond to changes in `IsSelected` in that class. Then put an instance of your `ViewCell` subclass in your `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate`.

The main advantage of this approach is better encapsulation -- instead of modifying a `ViewCell` from your `ListView`, your `ViewCell` will be updating itself. It also insulates you somewhat from having to know the internal workings of the `ListView`.

Check out [chapter 19 of Charles Petzold's book](https://download.xamarin.com/developer/xamarin-forms-book/BookPreview2-Ch19-Upd0728.pdf) (PDF) for lots of useful information about working with `ListView`s and `ViewCell`s.

Comment: Thanks. But I guess, in this case I would need a bindable StackLayout (like WP ItemsControl) which I cannot find in Xamarin.forms.

Comment: @Matt if you know the possible contents of the StackLayout ahead of time, you can include them and bind their IsVisible property to a bool. If you need to add an arbitrary number of items to the StackLayout on the ItemSelected handler, you also have the option of creating and adding the items in your ViewCell's code-behind. Or you may be interested in XLab's RepeaterView: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/RepeaterView